# Retrieve values at the same time as file attachment download

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form that triggers a file download:

```
function downloadEnhancedSubtitle ($subtitle,$totalSequences,$filename) {
    // Build string
    $subtitleString = '';
    foreach ($subtitle as $thisSegmentKey => $segment) {
        $sequenceString = $segment->sequence."\r\n";
        $sequenceString .= formatMilliseconds($segment->startTimeInMilliseconds).' --> '.formatMilliseconds($segment->endTimeInMilliseconds)."\r\n";
        if(isset($segment->textLine1)) $sequenceString .= utf8_decode($segment->textLine1)."\r\n";
        if(isset($segment->textLine2)) $sequenceString .= utf8_decode($segment->textLine2)."\r\n";
        if(isset($segment->textLine3)) $sequenceString .= utf8_decode($segment->textLine3)."\r\n";
        $sequenceString .= "\r\n";
        $subtitleString .= $sequenceString;
    }
    $subtitleString .= ($totalSequences+1)."\r\n99:99:90,000 --> 99:99:99,999\r\nEnhanced\r\n";

    // Download string
    header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=windows-1252");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($subtitleString));
    echo $subtitleString;
}
```

The user submits a subtitle file and it is "optimized" on the server and sent back to the user as an attachment download. But I would like at the same time (same form view where the file is downloaded) to trigger a modal with some data of the process, for example, how many lines where optimized.

As "Content-Disposition: attachment" automatically downloads everything printed on screen, is there any way I could retrieve the value of a variable using that response? Maybe changing everything to be an ajax request?
(using PHP on the backend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to save file on server then you can get response with all variables, but it's one problem - you need to delete all generated files for safety.

```
function downloadEnhancedSubtitle ($subtitle,$totalSequences,$filename) 
{
    [...]
    // Response for ajax
    echo json_encode(
        [
            'filename' => $filename,
            'link' => 'http://localhost/uploads/' . $filename,
            'subtitle' => $subtitleString
        ]
    );
}
```

**Javascript** (jQuery)

You are getting all your variables from server.

```
$.ajax({
    [...],
    success: function(response) {
        // if response is not object
        var obj = JSON.parse(response),
            filename = obj.filename,
            link = obj.link,
            subtitle = obj.subtitle;

        // if response is object
        var filename = response.filename,
            link = response.link,
            subtitle = response.subtitle;

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question, if I send the link to download the file do I need the filename or the subtitleString?

Comment: You need filename, because it's a link to place on the server where you saved the file.